# SQLite database sync over usb via PC

Tags: android, sqlite, usb

I have been given the task of creating
a simple Android Application that stores data on the devices database.

I assume it will be `SQLite` database.

The requirement is then is to connect the device via a **USB** cable to
a pc hosting a `SQLServer` database , Data from the `SQLite` database must
then be synchronize to the `SQLServer` database, i.e. data will be
pushed and pulled back to the `SQLite` database.

The specific requirement is for a **USB** connection as the devices will
not have internet connection much of the time. Therefore I am not
looking for a web service solution. The pc hosting the `SQLServer`
database is a stand alone PC with no internet connection.

This may seem archaic but that is how the users work ( i.e. mobile users
working in rural locations returning to an office pc in a cabin in the
wilderness on which they must all sync their days data, real time data
is not important, it is a `statistics/counts` collecting application)
The `SQLServer` database has a complex VB Application that sits on top
of it and works nicely so I cannot change the PC database.

I am looking for a workable solution, so mobile app, mobile database
and sync advise would be most appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: this is not possible; the Android USB connection to a host PC is not available for apps.

Comment: @CL. may be you are right but there are various apps sync data using USB connection like Samsung PC suit etc. what are these apps working mechanism

Comment: Samsung added another interface to the USB connection. Other apps still cannot access it.